# Join table error using Sequelize (findall is not a function) node.js

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, sql-server, sequelize.js

I'm using Sequelize and everything looks okay until there is a request I made from postman. An error displayed on the console

> TypeError: db.Invoicer.find is not a function

Here it is my code

**invoicer.model.js**

```
const { DataTypes } = require("sequelize");

module.exports = model;

function model(sequelize) {
  const attributes = {
    id:{type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,},
    clientname:{type: DataTypes.STRING(3999), allowNull: true},
    clientaddress:{type: DataTypes.STRING(3999), allowNull: true},
    clientdistrict:{type: DataTypes.STRING(3999), allowNull: true},
    clientcity:{type: DataTypes.STRING(3999), allowNull: true},
    clientprovince:{type: DataTypes.STRING(3999), allowNull: true},
    clientcountry:{type: DataTypes.STRING(3999), allowNull: true},
    clientponumber:{type: DataTypes.STRING(3999), allowNull: true},
    shipname:{type: DataTypes.STRING(3999), allowNull: true},
    shipaddress:{type: DataTypes.STRING(3999), allowNull: true},
    shipdistrict:{type: DataTypes.STRING(3999), allowNull: true},
    shipcity:{type: DataTypes.STRING(3999), allowNull: true},
    shipprovince:{type: DataTypes.STRING(3999), allowNull: true},
    shipcountry:{type: DataTypes.STRING(3999), allowNull: true},
    shipponumber:{type: DataTypes.STRING(3999), allowNull: true},
    customerpo:{type: DataTypes.STRING(3999), allowNull: true},
    shipvia:{type: DataTypes.STRING(3999), allowNull: true},
    shipdate:{type: DataTypes.STRING(3999), allowNull: true},
    termofpayment:{type: DataTypes.STRING(3999), allowNull: true},
    duedate:{type: DataTypes.STRING(3999), allowNull: true},
    invoicedate:{type: DataTypes.STRING(3999), allowNull: true},
    approvedby:{type: DataTypes.STRING(3999), allowNull: true},
    clientsignature:{type: DataTypes.STRING(3999), allowNull: true},
    additionalnotes:{type: DataTypes.STRING(3999), allowNull: true},
  };
  const options = {
    freezeTableName: true,
    // don't add the timestamp attributes (updatedAt, createdAt)
    timestamps: false,
  };
  return sequelize.define("Invoicer", attributes, options);
}
```

**items.model.js**

```
const { DataTypes } = require("sequelize");

module.exports = model;

function model(sequelize) {
  const attributes = {
    id:{
      type: DataTypes.STRING(3999),
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    invoiceid:{type: DataTypes.STRING(50), allowNull: true},
    currency:{type: DataTypes.STRING(3999), allowNull: true},
    itemdesc:{type: DataTypes.STRING(3999), allowNull: true},
    quantity:{type: DataTypes.STRING(3999), allowNull: true},
    unit:{type: DataTypes.STRING(3999), allowNull: true},
    price:{type: DataTypes.STRING(3999), allowNull: true},
    discount:{type: DataTypes.STRING(3999), allowNull: true},
    freightprice:{type: DataTypes.STRING(3999), allowNull: true},
    taxamount:{type: DataTypes.STRING(3999), allowNull: true},
    downpayment:{type: DataTypes.STRING(3999), allowNull: true},
  };
  const options = {
    freezeTableName: true,
    // don't add the timestamp attributes (updatedAt, createdAt)
    timestamps: false,
  };
  return sequelize.define("Items", attributes, options);
}
```

**db.js**

```
const { Sequelize } = require("sequelize");
const invoicerModel = require("../models/invoicer.model");
const itemsModel = require("../models/items.model");
require("dotenv").config();

const sequelize = new Sequelize(
  process.env.DB,
  process.env.USER,
  process.env.PASSWORD,
  {
    host: process.env.HOST,
    port: process.env.SQL_PORT,
    dialect: process.env.DIALECT,
    dialectOptions: {
      options: { encrypt: false },
    },
  }
);



const db = {};
db.Invoicer = invoicerModel(sequelize).hasMany(itemsModel(sequelize),{foreignKey:'invoiceid'});
db.Items = itemsModel(sequelize).belongsTo(invoicerModel(sequelize),{foreignKey:'id'});
sequelize.sync({ alter: true });


module.exports = db;
```

**invoicer.service.js**

```
const db = require("../config/db");

const getAll = async () => {
  return await db.Invoicer.findAll();
};

const findInvoiceById = async (id) => {
  return await db.Invoicer.findByPk(id);
};

const deleteInvoice = async (Id) => {
  await db.Invoicer.destroy({
    where: { Id: Id },
  });
};

module.exports = {
  getAll,
  findInvoiceById,
  deleteInvoice,
}
```

**invoicer.controller.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const InvoicerService = require("../services/invoicer.service");

router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    var invoice = await InvoicerService.getAll();
    res.json(invoice);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).json({ statusCode: 500, error: "Something went wrong" });
  }
});

router.get("/:id", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    var invoice = await InvoicerService.findInvoiceById(req.params.id);
    if (!invoice) {
      return res
        .status(404)
        .json({ statusCode: 404, error: "Invoice Does not exist" });
    }
    return res.json(invoice);
  } catch (error) {
    return res
      .statusCode(500)
      .json({ statusCode: 500, error: "Something went wrong" });
  }
});

router.delete("/:id", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    var exisitingInvoice = await InvoicerService.findInvoiceById(req.params.id);
    if (!exisitingInvoice) {
      return res
        .status(404)
        .json({ statusCode: 404, error: "Invoice Does not exist" });
    }

    await InvoicerService.deleteInvoice(req.params.id);
    return res.json({
      statusCode: 200,
      message: `invoice with id: ${req.params.id} is deleted successfully`,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    return res
      .statusCode(500)
      .json({ statusCode: 500, error: "Something went wrong" });
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

I want to join items table to invoice table with foreign key in the items table is invoiceid linked to id column in invoice table

**UPDATE**

here is the code that i tried in db.js file. the rest of the file is unchanged.

```
const { Sequelize } = require("sequelize");
const invoicerModel = require("../models/invoicer.model");
const itemsModel = require("../models/items.model");
require("dotenv").config();

const sequelize = new Sequelize(
  process.env.DB,
  process.env.USER,
  process.env.PASSWORD,
  {
    host: process.env.HOST,
    port: process.env.SQL_PORT,
    dialect: process.env.DIALECT,
    dialectOptions: {
      options: { encrypt: false },
    },
  }
);

const db = {}
const invoicer = invoicerModel(sequelize);
const items = itemsModel(sequelize);
invoicer.hasMany(items, { foreignKey:'invoiceid' });
db.Invoicer = invoicer;
items.belongsTo(invoicer, { foreignKey:'invoiceid' })
db.Items = items;

module.exports = db;
```

after i tried to send a request from postman it gave me this error

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Invoicer')

Answer (score 0):

Association functions return association objects and not models themselves. Call them  separately and that does the trick:

```js
const invoicer = invoicerModel(sequelize)
const items = itemsModel(sequelize)
invoicer.hasMany(items, { foreignKey:'invoiceid' });
db.Invoicer = invoicer;

// please pay attention that you need to indicate the same foreignKey value in both associations
items.belongsTo(invoicer, { foreignKey:'invoiceid' })
db.Items = items;
```

Comment: i'm sorry but it still give me an error, it says `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Invoicer')`. Any idea how to solve it? Thank you very much btw.

Comment: Could you update the post with with code piece used?